# Keeps getting p value = 1 in logistics regression

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a logistics regression to predict the probability of Democrats winning the election.

Response variable: democrat win = 1, democrat lose = 0.
Predictor variables:

- electoral rate for democrats in percent
- number of votes for democrats
- number of states voted for democrats
- if California voted for democrats, 1 = yes, 0 = no.

My data is from 1960 to 2016.

```
Name    Democrat_win    Electoral_rate_D_percent    Votes_for_D States_vote_D   CA_vote_D  
Ronald Reagan   0   9.1 49  7   0
Ronald Reagan   0   2.4 13  2   0
George Bush 0   20.6    111 11  0
William J. Clinton  1   68.8    370 33  1
William J. Clinton  1   70.4    379 32  1
George W. Bush  0   49.4    266 21  1
George W. Bush  0   46.7    251 20  1
Barack Obama    1   67.8    365 32  1
Barack Obama    1   61.7    332 27  1
Donald Trump    0   42.2    227 21  1
```

So I performed a glm in r and it's not working...p value of each predictor is 1. How do I proceed?

R code as follows:

```
election = read.csv("project.csv")
election
names(election)
attach(election)
election.glm1 = glm(Democrat_win~Electoral_rate_D_percent+States_vote_D, family = binomial, data = election)
summary(election.glm1)
```

outputs as following:

```
Call:
glm(formula = Democrat_win ~ Electoral_rate_D_percent + States_vote_D, 
    family = binomial, data = election)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-1.322e-05  -2.110e-08  -2.110e-08   2.110e-08   1.392e-05  

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)              -1.860e+02  3.363e+05  -0.001        1
Electoral_rate_D_percent  1.751e-01  1.918e+04   0.000        1
States_vote_D             7.344e+00  4.656e+04   0.000        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.3460e+01  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4.1815e-10  on 7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Comment: As a sidenote, it is unnecessary and inadvisable to use `attach`. It often leads to problems and rarely is beneficial. You can usually substitute `with` and in this instance, the use of the data argument in `glm` allows you to refer to variables directly by their name.

Comment: The model is "working" in the sense that it's converging and you're getting estimates. The issue is that you have such a tiny sample. With so few cases and a non-deterministic model, the standard errors on those estimates are inevitably huge, so your p-values are approximately 1.

Comment: Look up "separation" and "complete separation"

Comment: to add to @ekstroem's comment have a look at `with(election, plot(Democrat_win ~ Electoral_rate_D_percent))` . All  `Electoral_rate_D_percent > ~50` are democratic, hence separation.  Also probably a good idea to leave one of the predictors out as they are perfectly correlated. `with(election, cor(Electoral_rate_D_percent, Votes_for_D))` , another reason that se's can explode